# HTML Iframes overwrite document.write

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, overwrite, content-security-policy

**Main context**

- I inject a js script in every HTML page through a proxy
- My js code is the first evaluated script in the page
- I can modify the page with the proxy
- My goal is to add **a dynamic attribute to every scripts generated client side before the execution**.
- All function overwrites work properly except for the **write function**
- The page could have **IFrame nodes** statically or dynamically generated (or modifed!) which use the write function.

**Code**

In my injected script there is this code which overwrites the **native write function**, checks the content, if there are script tags it adds an attribute and recall the original function:

```js
...
var TYPE_WRITE = "type_write";
var f_write = HTMLDocument.prototype.write;
HTMLDocument.prototype.write = function () {
    arguments = my_mitm_function(arguments, TYPE_WRITE);
    return f_write.apply(this, arguments);
};
...
```

**Problems**

It works perfectly except in case of **"write" in a "IFrame"**, here an example:

```js
...
var myIFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(myIFrame);
myIFrame = (myIFrame.contentWindow) ? myIFrame.contentWindow : (myIFrame.contentDocument.document) ? myIFrame.contentDocument.document : myIFrame.contentDocument;
myIFrame.document.open();
myIFrame.document.write("<script>alert('Msg from inside');<\/script>");
myIFrame.document.close();
...
```

I think the problem is that every IFrame have a different document

Is there a way to **hook every "write" function in every "IFrame" context**?
or a way to get around ?

**More details**

- I need to add a "nonce" attribute because the CSP policy of the page does not allow scripts but only "nonce" attributes.
- I already tested other alternative such as 'MutationObserver' but my function must add the attribute before the CSP engine evalutation.